# Compose - use app theme inside other activities inside modules/libraries

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

When developing a library which also provides a compose activity, is there any way to use a user provided app theme inside the library?

My only solution so far is following:

```kotlin
// 1) define an interface for a theme provider
interface IThemeProvider : Parcelable {
    @Composable
    fun applyTheme(content: @Composable () -> Unit)
}

// 2) create an instance of this interface inside the user app
@Parcelize
object ThemeProvider : IThemeProvider {
    @Composable
    override fun applyTheme(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
        AppTheme(content)
    }
}

// 3) offer a function to start the activity of the library
fun start(context: Context, themeProvider: IThemeProvider) {
    val intent = Intent(context, SomeActivityInsideALibrary::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("themeProvider", themeProvider)
    context.startActivity(intent)
}

// now the activity inside the library can wrap it's content like following
val themeProvider = intent.getParcelableExtra<IThemeProvider>("themeProvider")
themeProvider.applyTheme {
    // content of the library activity will now be themed with the app theme
}
```

**Question**

This is cumbersome and if I offer this inside multiple libraries I must define this interface in everyone of them and actually I don't want that. In a view based activity I can simply use the app theme from the manifest or hand on a custom theme id to the activity - is there any easier way than mine that I did not discover yet?